# kubernetes nginx-ingress IP adress issue

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I am getting loopback address while using nginx-ingress controller on kubernetes microk8s

[image]

I am using microk8s and nginx-ingress tried different method using loadbalancer and nodeport but still giving the same result.